# Vue.js v-model in Laravel Blade @foreach multiple text input issue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Hi I have a Laravel app that views posts and comments. My issue is with the Vue v-model in the input text with my `@foreach` in Blade. It shows the comments input box for each post. When I add text to any input under a post then the text appears in every comment input on the page. How can I go about to only view the input text on the current input I am typing in and not each one?

My HTML:

```
                   @foreach($posts as $post)
                     <div class="row add-comment">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="addComment" placeholder="Add your comment" class="form-control" v-model="comment">
                          </div>
                          <input id="addComment" type="submit" name="submitComment" value="Submit Comment" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="submitComment({{ $post->id }})">
                        </div>

                      </div>
                   @endforeach
```

My Vue:

```
var posts = new Vue({
    el: "#posts",
    data: {
      comment: '',
    },

    methods: {
      submitComment: function(id){

        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
          }
        });

        $.ajax({
          url:'/post/comment/create/' + id,
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            comment: this.comment,
            post_id: id
          },

          success:function(response){
            toastr.success(response.response);
          },
          error: function(error){
            toastr.error(error.error)
          }
        });
      }
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are binding the same data attribute `comment` to every input. You need to create an array for your v-model to bind each element independently. Try the following:

```
 data: {
   comment: [],
 },

 <input type="text" name="addComment-{{ $post->id }}" placeholder="Add your comment" class="form-control" v-model="comment[{{ $post->id }}]">
```

You may need to initialize `comment: []` before hand to the length of `$posts`, I haven't tested this code.

Your ajax will need to be updated also:

```
data: {
    comment: this.comment[id],
    post_id: id
},
```

Comment: This breaks my code when I then try to submit it. The typing issue gets solved though.

Comment: How exactly does it break? Post error logs or exceptions if you can.

Comment: It gives error `500 Internal Server Error` and message under network tab is `Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Database\\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, integer given, called in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Grammars\\Grammar.php on line 681`. There is no log yet - my logs sometimes take a while to update. Is there a way to see the results in the log file quicker?

Comment: But I am still curious about the log file - now that it has been mentioned. Can it be updated somehow?

Comment: I haven't ever encountered a delay in writing to the log files, it should happen immediately when a loggable exception or logging statement is encountered. Perhaps your logfile is really large and it's taking a while to read in?